# Is there anything added to the last element in a single line of a MySql sql::ResultSet?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Okay so, a little background. I successfully grabbed a sql::ResultSet by establishing a connection and running my query. The MySQL query returns the appropriate information and I'm able to loop through it and output the text to a cell in my QTableWidget.

Once I was able to verify all of the information was correct, I set out to replace the text in those cells with a QIcon. During my test run, almost everything was correct, however I was unable to trigger my logic check for "Rock" or "Grass" in the last element of the ResultSet. Essentially, once I get to the final element in a ResultSet, the check for `else if (results->getString((i + 1)) == "Grass")` fails, and it goes to the *else statement*. This **only** happens to the last element in the ResultSet before we go back to the top of the *while* loop. The following replaces cells with "Grass" as the string with the icon, and does the same for "Rock".

I guess my question is if there is some sort of trailing whitespace, newline, or something that at the end of the final element of a ResultSet that would make me unable to match the string to the Icon?

```
void QtPlayground::DisplayTable(sql::ResultSet* results)
{
    int count = 0;
    QTableWidgetItem* item;
    QIcon icon;

    //keep looping through the result set
    while(result->next())
    {
        // Insert the new row before we start to display to our current data in QTableWidget
        ui.displayTable->insertRow(ui.displayTable->rowCount());
            
        // Loop throught the items in this current line of the ResultSet (took out extra 'else if' checks)
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // If GetString returns "Grass", put an icon in the cell instead of just the text
            if (results->getString((i + 1)) == "Grass")
            {
                    item = new QTableWidgetItem;
                    icon = QIcon(grassStr.c_str());
                    item->setIcon(icon);
            }
            // If GetString returns "Rock", put an icon in the cell instead of just the text
            else if (results->getString((i + 1)) == "Rock")
            {
                    item = new QTableWidgetItem;
                    icon = QIcon(rockStr.c_str());
                    item->setIcon(icon);
            }
            else
            {
                // If the type look-up fails, just output the data to the cell
                item = new QTableWidgetItem(results->getString((i + 1)).c_str());
            }
            
            // Output current item to the specific cell
            ui.displayTable->setItem(count, i, item);
        }
    }
}
```

And my current output is below (I removed a lot of the extra 'else if' statements that are exactly the same, they just take different strings).

[image: Current Output]

I appreciate any assistance that can be given on this.

Comment: *if there is some sort of trailing whitespace, newline, or something that at the end of the final element of a ResultSet that would make me unable to match the string to the Icon?* -- Use the debugger to determine this.  Or if not that, simply print the ASCII value of each character to see if there is a control character at the end of the string.

Comment: Yeah it's hard to attach the debugger to this process. I'll print out the ASCII values. I gave the tags I did because I thought maybe someone would have an idea that WASN'T the endline stuff, as that's all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was.  A result set is not a file, after all.

Comment: I mean, I can't say I disagree. It is a shot in the dark that a dataset would have standard line endings. I'm just at a loss at the moment since I can't attach a standard debugger to this project (Qt, CMake, and C++ in VS don't really play nice together innately).

Comment: If you get CMake to generate a PDB file, then you can launch the process and then attach the VS debugger to it once it's running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and dumping data to text files, it turns out that the end line of an sql::ResultSet actually has a `\r` appended to it, which would make the check fail. Obviously, the solution was to turn this check:

```
else if (results->getString((i )) == "Rock")
            {
                item = new QTableWidgetItem;
                icon = QIcon(rockStr.c_str());
                item->setIcon(icon);
            }
```

Into the following check:

```
else if (results->getString((i )) == "Rock" || results->getString((i)) == "Rock\r")
            {
                item = new QTableWidgetItem;
                icon = QIcon(rockStr.c_str());
                item->setIcon(icon);
            }
```

I honestly wouldn't have expected it to be a `\r` instead of a `\n`, but dumping the ASCII values out to the file was how I figured out that it was a CR over an LF (thanks comments).

Comment: How bizarre is that?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought honestly. Especially using the CR line ending. Also, thank you for the advice on the CMake debugger. You're a saint.

Comment: Not really, just another hacker.  GL